# Logo or image to aside from email subject

Tags: email

Is there any way to add you logo or image profile in this way? or how I can search more about this.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might just need to add an image to the sender's Google profile or to Gravatar:
http://blog.postmarkapp.com/post/129733989583/how-to-easily-add-a-sender-image-to-gmail

Comment: Thanks. Seems like only work with apps that support gravatar. I mean, if I open the email with hotmail the image is hidden, but, if I open it with mailbird I can see my gravatar.